# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “ ”

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, numberformatexception, java.lang.class

So the issue I am getting seems to be a kind of common, however the missing points in each of the issues I checked online was different from the one I experiencing.

So what I am trying to do is converting a string back to long. 
The string was read from a file as following

```
484625517161611266 string 454511457536
```

I read the line into an array and I printed the array which shows the writing went fine.
Then I tried convert to long as below

```
long id = Long.parseLong(splitted[0],10);
```

However I got this issue

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "﻿484625517161611266"
```

Normally the common issues with this type of exception would be trying to convert letter or trying to convert numbers that contains spaces. Another issue might be a certain mistake while reading the file.

However I check all of those possibilities and still I am getting this exception

Any Suggestions ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The FEFF is even in the string up there in the question, in the error message! ROFL.

Comment: It's the very first character.

Comment: The FEFF character is a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "484625517161611266"

There is a [`\uFEFF`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm)  (ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE) character in your input

Try copying it and pasting it in plain text editor, remove this junk character

to remove this character you can use

```
inputNumberString.replaceAll("\uFEFF", "").trim()
```

<sub>note: `trim()` just to remove any other whitespace if present</sub>

Comment: I don't think trim will take care of that.

Comment: yes and that is why _and remove this junk character_

Comment: It reads as if trim() will fix it. And if not, it's just some random extra advice :p Good catch though btw.

Comment: [String.trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) only removes some ASCII-domain characters, mainly spaces.

Comment: @keyser gave more weight on removing character

Comment: Because trim is not Unicode-aware - the full reason is in the linked documentation.

Comment: I didn't mention that trim will take care of it @user28

Comment: Then the answer needlessly mentions trim and associates it erroneously with "white space". Thus it only adds confusion.

Comment: @user28 answer mentions to use trim to avoid other cases where there is a whitespace character as well, it doesn't say that trim will fix it

Comment: would it be possible to remove the "/uFEFF" character using .replace function ?

Comment: plz take your discussion to a chat room